# How can I rewrite my sql query so that it returns the values in a specific format (using mysql or php)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have a table called `number`:

```
number_id  |  number_name
   1            aaaa
   2            bbbb
   3            cccc
   4            dddd
   5            eeee
   6            ffff
```

(it contains only 6 entries)

and also I have a table called `texts`:

```
text_id  |  start_time  |  number_id  |  text_content
   1        some date1  |     2       |    blabla1
   2        some date2  |     1       |    blabla2
   3        some date3  |     2       |    blabla3
   4        some date4  |     3       |    blabla4
   5        some date5  |     4       |    blabla5
   6        some date6  |     6       |    blabla6
  etc.
```

(it contains a lot of entries).

Now, when I'm doing a query like this:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   (SELECT
      DATEDIFF(now(),
      start_time) AS days_ago,
      number_id,
      COUNT(text_id) AS num_texts 
   FROM
      TEXTS 
   WHERE
      start_time BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 100 DAY) AND NOW() 
   GROUP BY
      DATE(start_time),
      number_id) AS temp
```

it returns me the number of texts on each day from the past 100 days on each place with number_id. The result looks like this:

[image]

And when I encode it to json, I get:

```
[{"days_ago":"19","number_id":"1","num_texts":"179"},
{"days_ago":"19","number_id":"5","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"18","number_id":"1","num_texts":"61"},
{"days_ago":"18","number_id":"2","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"18","number_id":"5","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"18","number_id":"6","num_texts":"3"},
{"days_ago":"17","number_id":"3","num_texts":"1"},
{"days_ago":"8","number_id":"1","num_texts":"2"},
{"days_ago":"8","number_id":"2","num_texts":"2"},
{"days_ago":"7","number_id":"4","num_texts":"1"},
```

I want to write a different query, or change the existing one. Is there a way of writing a query that will return me this data in a following way:

```
[{"days_ago": "7", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"},
{"days_ago": "6", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"},
{"days_ago": "5", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"},
{"days_ago": "4", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"},
{"days_ago": "3", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"},
{"days_ago": "2", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"},
{"days_ago": "1", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"}]
```

Basically each row should have the information about `days_ago` and the value `num_texts` for each one of 6 `number_id`'s. I need to limit this query for only past 7 days, so I know I can modify it here:

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 100 DAY) AND NOW()
```

and change 100 to 7, but is there a possibility of getting somehow the rest of the information in this specific format?

Oh and one more thing - I'm invoking this query from php, so if it's easier to parse it somehow in php and return as a json that's also an option.

Thanks a lot for any hints guys!

=========
EDIT:

As @AlexBlex pointed out - the json structure proposed by me might be invalid, because there are the same key names used several times. To help you understand my question better - http://thevectorlab.net/flatlab/morris.html here're examples of morris js charts. I want to produce the chart as the one called `Quarterly Apple iOS device unit sales` in that example. On horizontal line I want the dates (`days ago`), and on vertical line I need num_texts. I want to have 6 lines, each line for different number_id.

Comment: First of all, expected  `{"days_ago": "7", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3", "num_texts" : "12" , ... , "number_id" : "6", "num_texts" : "1"}` is invalid JSON. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627 reads: "The names within an object SHOULD be unique.". In the requested example you have 4 names `number_id` and 4 names `num_texts` within the same object.  
Secondly, is there any relation between `number.number_id` and `texts.number_id` ?

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks for the hint! I added a follow up edit to my question to make it more clear for understanding. And yes, the texts.number_id is the foreign key of number.number_id

Comment: No worries @user3766930, it would be nice if you edit your question with  json which actually works with your chart. You can mock your backend and play a bit with frontend to figure out which format fits you best. It may also worth to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks again :) My problem is that I don't know how to generate the json in correct form (in php) to fill the data in this morris chart..

Comment: You don't need to generate anything. **mock** it. Write your backend php script which return hardcoded json string. Something like `<php echo '[{"days_ago": "7", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12", "number_id" : "3"},
{"days_ago": "6", "number_id" : "1", "num_texts" : "18", "number_id" : "2", "num_texts" : "12"}]';` Check why your chart does not render it and change the string until you're happy with the chart. You may need to refer to charting software docs for supported formats. When you're happy with frontend, please post here the json which works.

Comment: Do you need the JSON to contain entries for `num_texts = 0`?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your `number` has these 6 fixed values that **will never change**, it is possible by linking 6 copies of the `texts` table (or create 6 views).

But it will probably be a lot cleaner if you do it in php by tracking when `days_ago` changes and adding a new JSON record. You will also have to make sure no `number_id` is skipped and add a zero value for `num_texts` for any skipped.

Addition, sample pseudo-code:

```
$days_ago=0;
while ([read_records]) {
    if (record['days_ago']!=$days_ago {
        $days_ago!=0 [Close line]
        $days_ago=record['days_ago'];
        [Add new line]
        [Add days_ago field]  }
    [Add number_id and num_texts fields]
}
[Close line]
```

Second Edit, solution with views:

If `view_1` is the view I described below and `view_2` the view for `number_id` `2`, you would link them like this:

```
SELECT view_1.days_ago, view_1.num_texts AS num_texts1, view_2.num_texts AS num_texts2
FROM view_1 INNER JOIN view_2 ON view_1.days_ago=view_2.days_ago
```

This willo only work properly if you have entries for all `number_id` for every `days_ago`, otherwise you will have to create a view of just the `days_ago` and use LEFT/RIGHT joins to join the `number_id` views.

Comment: yes, that assumption is correct, those numbers won't change. However, your hint with php sound more realistic at this point, I just have no idea how to even start with that, could you give me some example?

Comment: Do you have the capability of adding views to your MySQL database? That will make your life a lot easier. I will add some pseudo-code on how you would do it with php.

Comment: yes, I do have a possibility of creating views, but I'm not sure how would it make things easier here?

Comment: create one view for each `number_id`, then link them together using days_ago.

`SELECT (now(), start_time) AS days_ago, COUNT(text_id) AS num_texts 
FROM TEXTS
WHERE number_id=1 AND start_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 100 DAY) AND NOW() 
GROUP BY DATE(start_time)` for `1`

Comment: It is the same as linking 6 copies of the main table, but without the mess of having to do it all in a single SQL statement

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort and sorry fo asking so many questions... I'm still not sure how could I link them, sorry, I'm a total beginner in this area :( could you give me some more detailed example?

Comment: I edited my answer with a very basic example of how you could go about it. It should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a pivot table:

```
SELECT
   days_ago,
   SUM(IF(number_id = 1, num_texts, 0)) as num_1_texts,
   SUM(IF(number_id = 2, num_texts, 0)) as num_2_texts,
   SUM(IF(number_id = 3, num_texts, 0)) as num_3_texts,
   SUM(IF(number_id = 4, num_texts, 0)) as num_4_texts,
   SUM(IF(number_id = 5, num_texts, 0)) as num_5_texts,
   SUM(IF(number_id = 6, num_texts, 0)) as num_6_texts
FROM
   (SELECT
      DATEDIFF(now(),start_time) AS days_ago,
      number_id,
      COUNT(text_id) AS num_texts 
   FROM
      TEXTS 
   WHERE
      start_time BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 100 DAY) AND NOW() 
   GROUP BY
      DATE(start_time),
      number_id)

GROUP BY days_ago;
```

If the amount of numbers is arbitrary, you could generate the field list with whatever language you are using.

in php:

```
$selectFields = '';
$numbers = 10;
$separator = ''
for($i=1; $i<=$numbers; $i++) {
    $selectFields .= $separator . "SUM(IF(number_id = {$i}, num_texts, 0)) as num_{$i}_texts";
    $separator = ',';
}

$query = "
    SELECT
    days_ago,
    $selectFields
    FROM
       (SELECT
          DATEDIFF(now(),start_time) AS days_ago,
          number_id,
          COUNT(text_id) AS num_texts 
       FROM
          TEXTS 
       WHERE
          start_time BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 100 DAY) AND NOW() 
       GROUP BY
          DATE(start_time),
          number_id)
    ORDER BY days_ago      
    GROUP BY days_ago;
";
```

Of course as someone pointed out, you have duplicate ids in your JSON, but it could easily be represented as:

```
[{days_ago: "1", numbers: [{"id" : "1", "num_texts" : "12"},...{"id": "n", "num_texts": "999"}],
{days_ago: "2", numbers: [{"id" : "1", "num_texts" : "12"},...{"id": "n", "num_texts": "999"}],
...
```

Or whatever format Morris.js is expecting. You would have the days on one axis and num_texts on the other. You may also need to handle the case where there was no activity on a specific day.

Comment: As per Alex Blex's suggestion, if you post some hardcoded JSON to generate the chart, it will be easier for us to know how to dynamically generate it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT DATEDIFF(now(), start_time) AS days_ago, number_id, COUNT(text_id) AS num_texts
                    FROM TEXTS 
                    WHERE start_time BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 100 DAY) AND NOW() 
                    GROUP BY DATE(start_time), number_id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        // convert to 2D array
        while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            if (!isset($res_ar[$result['days_ago']]))
            {
                $res_ar[$result['days_ago']] = array_fill(1, 6, 0);
            }

            $res_ar[$result['days_ago']][$result['number_id']] = $result['num_texts'];
        }

        // fill-in empty rows
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists($x, $res_ar))
            {
                $res_ar[$x] = array_fill(1, 6, 0);
            }
        }

        // convert to nested arrays
        foreach ($res_ar as $days_ago => $texts)
        {
            $res_out[$days_ago]['days_ago'] = $days_ago;
            foreach ($texts as $id => $count)
            {
                $res_out[$days_ago]['counts'][$id]['number_id'] = $id;
                $res_out[$days_ago]['counts'][$id]['num_texts'] = $count;
            }
        }

        // convert nested PHP arrays to nested JSON object
        $json = json_encode($res_out);
    ?>
```

I haven't actually run this, so I make no guarantee regarding bugs, but it should at least get you started.